# Auto Copy a Value from a Cell and Paste it in Another Cells in another row

Tags: excel

i need a ms excel formula which automatically do like this

```
it should copy the value in 
`B1` and should paste it from `A1` to `A7` and then copy the value in
`B8` and should paste it from `A8` to `A14` and then copy the value in
`B15`and should paste it from `A15` to `A21` and so on...
```

hope you understand, if not please let me know. i will try to expand my question
thank you!

waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=OFFSET($B$1,ROUNDDOWN((ROW($A1)-1)/7,0)*7,0)`

Paste this into A1 and drag it down.

**Explanation:**

`ROW` returns the current row.

`ROUNDDOWN` with the division and multiplication by 7 just rounds the current row down to the nearest multiple of 7. When you drag the formula down, it will output 0s for the first 7 rows, then 7s for the next seven rows, etc.

`OFFSET` gives you the value of the cell at B#, where # is the row given by `ROUNDDOWN`.

Comment: bro this worked. but didn't saved me :( please have a look on my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072448/copy-a-value-from-a-row-to-another-row-based-on-a-condition hope you can help....

Answer (score 0):

Jack beat me to it, but leaving this as a slightly different approach...

In B1:

```
=INDIRECT("B" & 1+((CEILING(ROW()/7,1)-1)*7))
```

Fill down.

Comment: bro what is the difference between jacks and your answer.. sorry i am unable to get the difference.. your answer didn't worked for me :(

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time for me. kindly please look at me new question, it is also similar to this, but difficult one :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072448/copy-a-value-from-a-row-to-another-row-based-on-a-condition thank you bro! :)