# Copy a Value from a row to another row based on a condition

Tags: excel

Friends i need a excel formal, struggling for some thing like this form past few days :(

```
it should search for the value in  which starts with `01` in `B row`
and past that value in `A1,A2,A3,A4.......` till it got another value in `B row`
which stars with `01`.
```

- in my table `B1` will start with `01` for 100%

so after `B1` if `B27` has a value starting with `01`, this formal should copy the `B1` value from `A1` to `A26`

from `A27` it should past the value of `B27` (from `A27` to some other cell in B row which starts with `01` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your English could be better ^^;

Anyway, if I understand well, it seems to me that a simple `IF()` would suit you.

In `A2`, put:

```
=IF(LEFT(B2,2)="01",B2,A1)
```

In `A1`, just put the value of `B1` yourself since the formula can't reference to cell `A0`.

Then just drag down the formula.

Comment: bro thanks for taking time. but not helped. i have updated my question with a small example like thing. please check

Comment: it works :) sorry :) i am trying to select this as answer. but it is showing me that i have to wait a min more to select this answer. thanks a lot bro :)